# Map path problem

Tags: iphone

I want to show the path between the start & the end location inserted for the map. How can i do the whole process? It is not showing the path though i am getting the latitude & longitude properly.

Comment: Path as in a straight line, or path as in some sort of directions between the two points?

Comment: It may be either straight or some sort of direction between two points. Right now I have the requirement of the second option (some sort of directions between the two points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",sourcelocation.latitude,sourcelocation.longitude,destinationlocation.latitude,destinationlocation.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
```